# (#100) Object does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permission or reviewable feature, or does not support this operation

Tags: facebook-graph-api

We want to develop a website on which users can publish photos on their behalf on their business Instagram account.
We have created a facebook application and we have done all the steps on
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started

to add user's Instagram account in our website.
In the mentioned link it is said that `instagram_basic` and `pages_show_list` permissions are needed so we have requested them and `pages_show_list`, `pages_read_engagement`, `instagram_basic` are approved and we switched our app to live mode.
When we test with a facebook developer account, we have problem with step 5 (Get the Page's Instagram Business Account `GET /{page-id}?fields=instagram_business_account`) in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started, we get this error:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#100) Object does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permission or reviewable feature, or does not support this operation. This endpoint requires the 'pages_read_engagement' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature or the 'Page Public Metadata Access' feature. Refer to https://developers.facebook.com/.../login-permissions..., https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature... and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature... for details.","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"Aus-C-rSHZld-9rLWtVUJdC"}}
```

And when we test with a usual facebook account we have problem with step 4 (Get the User's Pages `GET /{user-id}/accounts`) in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started, we get empty response although the facebook account has different facebook pages.

Comment: Did you copy&paste this from somewhere else, or why are all the links broken? Please fix.

Comment: I edited the links.

Comment: Did the user actually grant all the permissions you asked for? What user role do they have on the page in question?

Comment: when user is redirected to facebook login page, it seems getting permissions and editing setting is skipped and user is redirected to my call back url. I don't see permissions page. How can I stop facebook from skipping these steps?

Comment: That's normal, if the user already granted all the asked-for permissions, then they don't get asked again. (Would be annoying, if that happened every single time you log in.)

Comment: You are right but the permissions were approved after my last login and at the moment I'm not asked for the new permissions. Of course I'm not sure that my problem is related to this or not.

Comment: _"and we switched our app to live mode"_ - why, when you are still in the developing stage? I'd first of all switch it back, and test & develop then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241456/discussion-between-hoda-kh-and-cbroe).

Comment: I checked https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ .For generating access token I just see pages_show_list and instagram_basic permissions. Other permissions are not asked although they are approved.

Comment: Can you please debug the actual access token you used for this request here, https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/ - in the "Granular Scopes" section, does it say "Applies to all objects" for these permissions, or does it show any restriction to specific pages?

Comment: just for instagram_basic says Applies to all objects but pages_show_list is restricted to one facebook page that I have chosen when logged in.

Comment: Go to https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications and completely remove the app from there, and then try and login again - it should ask you which pages you want to give access to again at that point then.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is somehow solved for me with a developer facebook account but when I test with a non-developer facebook account, none of the permissions are asked and when I check https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/ just public_profile is set.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured this out. The issue was I put Authorization : "Bearer " outside headers. If you put Authorization : "Bearer " inside  headers, it should solve this problem. It will look something like this.

headers: {
"Content-Type": "application/json",
Authorization:
"Bearer ",
},